# Can I call this anonymous function in jQuery by triggering something?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hoverintent

I'm using the [hoverIntent jQuery plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) in place of jQuery's `hover()` method. I want the *mouseout* event to be called automatically.

When using `hover()`, I can trigger the mouseout event by calling `mouseout()`. This doesn't work when using hoverIntent.

I also tried calling a named anonymous function, but it didn't work for me (and I hear older IEs don't like named anonymous functions).

[Here is an example on jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/KXccW/)

If I auto invoke the *mouseout* function, it can't be called via hoverIntent.

Now I know I could do...

```
$('something').hoverIntent(function() { }, something);

something();
```

But I was wondering if what I wanted was possible?

Thanks

Comment: "named anonymous function" makes no sense :P

Comment: "named anonymous functions" :) => "named functions with no name"

Comment: @BoltClock - great minds, etc. :)

Comment: @karim79 @BoltClock I know it doesn't make sense, but isn't that what they are called? :S

Comment: @alex: "named function" as Nick says.

Comment: it would be a 'named nested function'.  not sure why you'd want to do that tho

Comment: @alex - No. They're called functionally anonymous named anomalies. (FANA)

Comment: @karim79 Serious? That's a mouthful.

Comment: @alex - Not serious. Sorry, I'm fooling around :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there's not a way besides a named function, not with how the plugin is structured...it's not stored in any way that's accessible later, only to the plugin's closure.

It's set here:

```
$.fn.hoverIntent = function(f, g) {
    // default configuration options
    var cfg = {
        sensitivity: 7,
        interval: 100,
        timeout: 0
    };
    // override configuration options with user supplied object
    cfg = $.extend(cfg, g ? {
        over: f,
        out: g
    } : f);
```

...then after that all references are to that `cfg` object which is only accessible inside the plugin.  If you wanted to *change* the plugin and store that `cfg` object via `.data()` for example you could, but as-is there's no way to access or trigger either anonymous handler.